# How to completely control the displayed title of a window?

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, notebooks, dialog-window

I can't quite seem to find a way to accomplish this task. I want to display an image in its own window with a custom title. This code almost accomplishes the task:

```
CreateDialog[
 {Image@Graphics[{Circle[]}]},
 
 WindowTitle -> "Circle",
 WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "ResizeArea", "MinimizeBox", 
   "ZoomBox"}
 ]
```

but there are ugly grey margins around the image.

This code gets rid of the grey margins:

```
CreateDialog[
 {Image@Graphics[{Circle[]}]},
 
 WindowTitle -> "Circle",
 WindowFrame -> "Normal",
 WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "ResizeArea", "MinimizeBox", 
   "ZoomBox"}
 ]
```

but now the title appends "- Wolfram Mathematica 13.2" in the title bar. How can I get rid of the grey margins in the output of the first example while retaining total control over the window title?

Comment: With 12.1 on a Mac, the title is just "Circle" for both snippets.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am on Windows, with 13.2. Interesting note, however.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the margins is to use the

```
PlotRangePadding -> None
```

option in Graphics. Using this with the first example gives one control over the window title completely, so my problem is solved sufficiently.